# Binding Issue constructor viewmodel

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I relatively new to mvvm, however I have a question about binding from a viewmodel.
I have a viewmodel where in its constructor I want to populate a observablecollection.
My constructor looks like this:

```
public StudySelectionViewModel() : base() {
        _studyRepository = StudyRepository.Instance;

        InitializeViewModelData();
    }
```

The InitializeViewModelData() looks like this:

```
        private void InitializeViewModelData() {
        _studyRepository.RetrieveModalityTypes();
        RaisePropertyChanged("ModalityTypes");
    }
```

My property ModalityTypes looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ModalityType> ModalityTypes {
        get {
            return _studyRepository.ModalityTypes;
        }
    }
```

Probably needless to say that my repository makes a call to a database and retrieves the data.
When debugging it looks like that the RaisePropertyChanged is executed earlier than my _studyRepository.RetrieveModalityTypes method is executed and hence it binds to an empty property.

Am I missing something here? Is my design bad? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The binding will inspect the property when the form initialises. It will also inspect the property when the `PropertyChanged` notification is raised - so you may get two calls to the getter of the property

I'm assuming that your call to get data is a web service call or something? Silverlight is async, so you need to consider that web service calls may return well after your form is initialised

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed, it is a call to web service.

Comment: It's worth asking - are you using any sort of MVVM framework?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider here.

1. You have an ObservableCollection - it's observable, so if you initialise the collection when you initialise the view model, the add to the collection rather than replacing it with a new collection when your data service returns the view will update fine.
2. If you really must replace the collection with a new collection in the data service data ready callback, then ensure you write the collection setter thus:

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<ModalityType> ModalityTypes {
   get {
       return _studyRepository.ModalityTypes;
   }
   set
      {
         this.__studyRepository.ModalityTypes = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("ModalityTypes");
      {
   ```

   }

Comment: ps.  be sure not to write directly to the property backing source _studyRepository.ModalityTypes,  otherwise the binding system will be unaware of changes.  Always work through the public property the view is bound to.